# It's Extremingly slow at calling CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString second time

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

I use CTFramesetter in while loop, just like codes bellow

```
CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) attrString);
while (hasMorePages) {
    ...
    if (buffer run out) {
       attrString = following Attributed String
       CFRelease(frameSetter);
       // following line takes several minutes.
       frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) attrString);
    }
}
```

My environment is iOS 6.1 simulator. anyone know what's the problem with it?

texts in attributed string is chinese.

Comment: profile your program?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that there are many unrecognizable characters in [following attributed String] which slow down the CTFrameSetterCreateWithAttributedString